# I am a beginner in Perl, How to go forward? Please, check the code

Tags: perl

This is the code I wrote, I am unable to get the part where I decrease the no of beers by 1

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# your code goes here

for($i =99; $i >= 0; $i--)
{
    print "$i bottles of beer on the wall, $i bottles of beer
Take one down and pass it around, $i bottles of beer on the wall.\n";
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post your code as part of the question (in text) rather than as a screen shot?

Comment: If you're asking for a code review, this belongs on the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I am unable to edit it properly, I guess and hence, it is not accepting the code.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your code *does* decrease the number of beers by 1. What do you mean you don't "get" it? (Is this not actually your code?)

Comment: Well, the actual lyrics are
"99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, 98 bottles of beer on the wall."

The number in the second line should decrease by 1, with my code it isn't?

Comment: If `$i` is 99, then `$i - 1` is 98. If I had no idea how to program in Perl, I would start by replacing the second `$i` with `$i - 1`. But that wouldn't work. So I would try to figure out a way to evaluate mathematical expressions inside a string. That's the kind of process you should be going through to solve problems like this. And if you can show us the steps you took along the way, it makes it much easier for us to gauge your current level of understanding so we can write better answers for you.

Comment: @MattJacob Broken code is off-topic on Code Review. Please read the [guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777), and avoid making inappropriate referrals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ($i = 99 ; $i > 0; ) {
    print "$i bottles of beer on the wall, $i bottles of beer
Take one down and pass it around, ", --$i, " bottles of beer on the wall.\n";
}
```

I leave it as an exercise for you to switch from "bottles" to "bottle" when you reach the last one...